# How to retrieve service credentials for Hyperledger on Kubernetes Cluster on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger

I recently installed Hyperledger on a Kubernetes cluster on IBM Bluemix trial account.

I want to use the Hyperledger Fabric SDK Node.js to access my blockchain. I am following the instructions to run the HLF SDK sample helloblockchain.js

https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain-Archive/SDK-Demo

I need to be able to retrieve my "service credentials". Since this is not the enterprise install on Bluemix I do not have a blockchain dashboard from which I can view credentials. How do I find my credentials to create the ServiceCredentials.json file?

Clarification:
When you install Hyperledger in a bluemix trial in a container you do not have the same Blockchain dashboard as you do if you added the Blockchain Enterprise service.
[blockchain dashboard in trial account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcqMb.jpg)

If you click on the blockchain item you get the cluster dashboard. There is no service credentials option Or option to create service credentials.

Answer (score 0):

When on the Bluemix dashboard, click on the Blockchain service and then on "service credentials" in the left column. This is where you'll find the credentials, if there isn't any click "create new credentials".

Comment: Thanks. Please see clarification I added above. I can't embed images (something about stackoverflow reputation??) but basically the issue is that in the Blockchain Enterprise plan you can access service credentials but in a trial account where you manually install Hyperledger in a container this option is not available. You do not have the same Blockchain dashboard as you do with an Enterprise Blockchain install.